# Scalar variables and registers : CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

I think CUDA would try to allocate scalar variables in registers, and in a Fermi class GPU, each thread has 63 registers.
My code is like this:

```
__global__ void test20 (double a)
{
    double i1=1.0;
    double i2=2.0;
    double i3=3.0;
    double i4=4.0;
    double i5=5.0;
    double i6=6.0;
    double i7=7.0;
    double i8=8.0;
    double i9=9.0;
    double i10=10.0;
    ...

    a = i1+i2+i3 ... i20
 }
```

But when I see the number of registers per thread using NVVP, I only see 2 registers allocated per thread, when I expected a higher number. Even if I decrease the variables to 10, the amount of registers allocated remains the same. Why is this happening and how do I ensure if I have n-variables, CUDA uses n-registers (considering the each variable could be stored in a single register)?

EDIT:

Following the advices, I have modified the code like this:

```
 __global__ void test (double *a)
{
    double reg1;
    double reg2;
    double reg3;
    double reg4;
    double reg5;
    double reg6;
    double reg7;
    double reg8;
    ....till 40
    reg1 = log10f(a[0]);
    reg2 = log10f(a[1]);
    reg3 = log10f(a[2]);
    reg4 = log10f(a[3]);
    reg5 = log10f(a[4]);
    reg6 = log10f(a[5]);
    reg7 = log10f(a[6]);
    reg8 = log10f(a[7]);
    reg9 = log10f(a[8]);
    ....till 40
    a[0] = reg1;
    a[1] = reg2;
    a[2] = reg3;
    a[3] = reg4;
    a[4] = reg5;
    a[5] = reg6;
    a[6] = reg7;
    a[7] = reg8;
   }
```

I am `memcpy`-ing the array `a` back to host. I now see all 63 registers are used per thread: `ptxas info    : Used 62 registers, 40 bytes cmem[0]`. Although I pass a lot more
variables than could fit in the registers, I don't see any spills to the local memory; I think NVCC is optimizing the code to use only registers.

Comment: it's compiler optimization. the compiler can precompute the result and substitute a constant.

Comment: Can you suggest how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: use expressions which can't be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Also, note that you can declare a small array, and the compiler will put the elements in registers, provided the index can be computed... at compile time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow @talonmies suggestion to use expressions that can't be evaluated at runtime you may still not get a register per declaration (or in this case 2 registers to hold a double). You may also have to keep the variable alive for the duration.

```
__global__ void test20 (double a)
{
    double i1=1.0 * a;
    double i2=2.0 * i1;
    double i3=3.0 * i2;
    double i4=4.0 * i3;
    double i5=5.0 * i4;

    a = i1+i2+i3+i4+i5;

    printf("a = %f = %f + %f + %f + %f + %f\n", a, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5);
}
```

This is sample code written in a browser. The goal is to retain values in registers. This sample has no practical application as the goal of the compiler is to use minimal registers. The only value in this is for debugging to keep variables alive for the duration of their scope.

If you want to understand register usage you should use cuobjump -sass to dump the assembly code for the kernel.

Comment: It is worth noting that without the printf call, a global memory write which involves the values of all of the double values would be required to prevent the same optimisation problem.

Comment: I think I would use an array instead of variables as @ArchaeaSoftware suggested to shorten the code

Comment: @sayan: make sure you understood *all* of ArchaeaSoftware's comment in that case.